# wildcard query doesn't return any results

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Im trying to query `Elasticsearch` with wildcard using `query_string`,
my query is:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "resources",
        "query": {
         "query_string": {
          "query": "resources.data:*gotomeeting.com*"
         }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The query doesn't return any results even though i know that my index looks something like that:

```
{
  'main_url': 'some_url',
  'resources': [
    {
      'actual_url': 'more_specific_url', 
      'data': 'general public.<a href="https://www3.gotomeeting.com/register/717380990" target="_blank">&#8220;FReSH:'
    },
    {
      'actual_url': 'other_url', 'data':'more_data'
    }
                ]
}
```

This is the settings of my index:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "whitespace",
          "char_filter": [
            "my_char_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "my_char_filter": {
          "type": "html_strip"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "main_url"
        ],
        "excludes": [
          "resources.data",
          "resources.actual_url"
        ]
      },
      "properties": {
        "main_url": {
          "type": "text", "norms": false,
          "analyzer": "standard"
        },
        "resources": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "actual_url": {
              "type": "text", "norms": false,
              "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "data": {
              "type": "text", "norms": false,
              "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I wonder what went wrong in the process, and how to make this query to return results.

Comment: Why do you need the wildcards? You lose a lot of performance by allowing wildcards at the beginning **and** the end. I am not as much in to your use case as you but you will get a lot of trouble when running these wilcards against a lot of data.
You should get hits by running a "classic" fullt text search (match query) on that particular field.

Comment: Hi, i need to search for domains inside html data. i'm using HTML strip but sometimes the core domains inside of a bigger domains. For example: ***gotomeeting.com/register*** is in https://www3.gotomeeting.com/register/717380990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, I had "<\a" before the url i was searching. The problem was that `html_strip` strips everything mentioned after "<\a" (The  tag defines a hyperlink).
That is, apparently part of `html_strip`'s logic is ignoring urls.
It can be simply worked around by adding "a" to the `escaped_tags`

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-htmlstrip-charfilter.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try the [Wildcard Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)? It returns documents that contain terms matching a wildcard pattern.

I think that your query can look something like:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "resources.data": {
                "value": "*gotomeeting.com*",
                "boost": 1.0,
                "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend you to check also the [Rewrite documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html) for this.

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: Hi, beside that that your query is not good for my index format, (`resources.data` is a nested field, you should use nested query format) you are right, im not obligated to use query_string. i forgot to mention that the following query doesn't work as well:  
```GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "resources",
      "query": {
        "wildcard": {
          "resources.data": "*gotomeeting.com*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```